# IndexError: list index out of range Why?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, indexoutofrangeexception

I know that this question has been answered so many times, but I can't figure out where my issue is. This is my code:

```
from random import*

def VerificationLongue():

    x=randint(0,1000)
    liste=CreerListe()
    Check=0
    i=0

    while i<=len(liste):
        if x==liste[i]:
            Check=Check+1
        i=i+1

    print("X est dans la liste",Check," fois")

def CreerListe(): 
    ListeAleatoire=[]
    for i in range (0,100):
        valeur=randint(0,1000)
        ListeAleatoire.append(valeur)
    return (ListeAleatoire)


VerificationLongue()
```

This is a simple algorithm to find if a number is in a list of random numbers. I know there is function such 'count', or 'in' but this is for school and they don't want us to use them. So there is the error I get:

```
line 11, in VerificationLongue
    if x==liste[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know why there is this error because it is initialized to 0.

Comment: `while i<=len(liste):` - if `i == len(liste)`, `i` is *beyond the end of the list*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
while i<=len(liste):
```

`i` can be equals to `len(liste)`. And it shouldn't. You have to use `i<len(liste)`:

```
>>> l = range(5)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> len(l)
5
>>> l[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> l[4]
4
```

---

Side note: you could use comprehension to do your while loop:

```
>>> liste = [randrange(10) for _ in xrange(20)]
>>> liste
[4, 4, 0, 7, 6, 6, 2, 9, 8, 1, 4, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 7, 4, 0, 2]
>>> x=randint(0,10)
>>> x
4
>>> sum(x == i for i in liste)
6
```

But lists also have a `count` method:

```
>>> liste.count(x)
6
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got `i<=len(liste)` but the last element of your list will occur at index `len(liste)-1`, meaning you'll get an `IndexError`.

You can fix this by replacing it with `i < len(liste)`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is `print i` in your loop and you'll easily see why it's happening.

Your loop should be `i < len(liste)` rather than `<=`. Lists are indexed from zero, so if you have 100 items they are numbered 0-99. By uising `<=` you are going from 0-100, and `liste[100]` does not exist.